# Insert de números antes da variável

Tags: php

Pretendo inserir a variável telefone com o 351 antes da variável, estou a tentar desta forma:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO raddb.Utente (telefone) VALUES ( ?)';
$stmt = $conn->prepare( $query );
$stmt->bind_param("s", 351$telefone);
$stmt->execute();
```

Mas desta forma não insere. Também tentei assim:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO raddb.Utente (telefone) VALUES ( 351?)';
$stmt = $conn->prepare( $query );
$stmt->bind_param("s", $telefone);
$stmt->execute();
```

Mas também sem sucesso

Comment: Por que não concatena a variável? ex: `'351'.$telefone`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Precisa concatenar com o* `.` *da seguinte forma*, (`$telefone = '351'.$telefone;`), ***exemplo***:

```
$telefone = '351'.$telefone;
$query = 'INSERT INTO raddb.Utente (telefone) VALUES (?)';
$stmt = $conn->prepare( $query );
$stmt->bind_param("s",$telefone);
$stmt->execute();
```

a segunda forma, não daria certo.

Comment: concatene antes: '$telefone = '351'.$telefone e depois insira apenas $telefone

Comment: vou editar! faça isso, concatene antes `$telefone = '351'.$telefone;`

Comment: Ele apagou o comentário dele.. Bruno, não é interessante apagar os comentários ou respostas, visto que pode ajudar outras pessoas com os mesmo problemas.. e ainda por cima fica parecendo que eu e o @Virgilio Novic 'falamos sozinho' kkk

Comment: @Gleidson Henrique apaguei o comentário porque pensei que era erro meu, mas depois de voltar a testar não insere se concatenar dentro do insert